# I can't read data from firebase or firestore

Tags: java, firebase, flutter, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore

i have a question, why my code doesn't work i want to read data from firebase or firestore the data to read is 2 humidity and temperature, but my code doesn't work

note: there also error when running in terminal

> pub get failed (1; Because nodemcu_dht11 depends on cloud_firestore ^0.4.4 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.)

and bunch of error in debugger

maybe you all can help me thanks.

````
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

await db.collection('data').doc('DHT22').get()
  .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                            
    firestoreTemp = documentSnapshot.data()['temp'];

    firestoreHumd = documentSnapshot.data()['humd'];

  }
);
void main() =>  runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                "https://blog.static.mamikos.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Polman.jpg"
                ),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ), 
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                Text(firestoreTemp),
                Text(firestoreHumd),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Fix your pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: How to fix pubspec.yaml? @HuthaifaMuayyad

Comment: What's the version in your `pybspec.yaml`? How about changing it to a recent one?